# Code to check for symmetry fails some test cases

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running into trouble trying to get this piece of code to run for all cases:

```
def symmetric(p):
    """ returns true if list is symmetric"""
    if p==[]:return True
    n=len(p)
    m=len(p[0])
    if m !=n:
        return False
    i=0
    j=0
    t=False
    while i < n:
        while j < n:
            if not p[i][j]==p[j][i]:
                return False
            j=j+1
        i=i+1
    return True
```

When I run this, it passes for some cases. 
I can't seem to see what I am doing wrong.

I'd expect `[['algebra', 'combinatorics', 'graphs'], ['combinatorics', 'topology', 'sets'], ['graphs', 'topology', 'sets']]` to return `False` but it doesn't.

Comment: Please do give us your cases that pass and don't pass.

Comment: my procedure did not return False for input [[1, 2], [1, 2]]

Comment: Please do [edit] your question to add details like that. Any more cases, including *correct* cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `break` statement only ends the *inner* `while` loop.

Since you already found an asymmetry, just use return:

```
i, j = 0
while i < n:
    while j < n:
        if not p[i][j] == p[j][i]:
            return False
        j += 1
    i += 1
return True
```

However, you are not comparing each row with each column at the same index here; because you never reset `j` back to 0, after the first `while j < n` loop you'll have `j == n` and you skip all the remaining loops.

Set `j = 0` *inside* the first `while`:

```
i = 0
while i < n:
    j = 0
    while j < n:
        if not p[i][j] == p[j][i]:
            return False
        j += 1
    i += 1
return True
```

Better still, use `for` loops over `range()`:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if not p[i][j] == p[j][i]:
            return False
return True
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have one case where it does not pass as below: "Your procedure did not return False for input [['algebra', 'combinatorics', 'graphs'], ['combinatorics', 'topology', 'sets'], ['graphs', 'topology', 'sets']]". This question  by the way is an optional quiz from udacity intro to computer science track